# Installed 64bit Ubuntu and no Wifi hardware showing at all but works fine on 32bit

Tags: wireless, hardware

I have installed Ubuntu AMD64 on my HP Pavilion i5 laptop but there is no WiFi hardware. When I run the command lshw there was no WiFi card found at all.

I removed AMD64 and installed the i386 package and that's what I'm on now. WiFi was detected and setup with no issues. I was going to carry on running this 32bit version but now when I come to download other software it only gives me 64bit options that do not install.

When I run lshw in 32bit it's listed with these details

```
description: Wireless interface
product: Intel Corporation
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
logical name: wlo1
version: 10
serial: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
width: 64bit
clock: 33mhz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.8.0-37-generic firmware=22,361476.0 ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

Can you help me get it working please.

Thanks

Comment: Weird indeed. Was the WiFi recognized in the 64bit live session when you were installing it?

Comment: What is the output of: `nmcli -f in-use,ssid,bssid,signal,bars dev wifi`?

Comment: Just testing 16.04 AMD64 in live and there is no WiFi option in top right menu and not displayed using lshw. The Ethernet is there.

There is no output from that command.

Comment: Still in Live: If I use lshw -class network, there are two listings.

*-network
description: Ethernet Interface
product: RTL8101 ..........

*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Network Controller
product: Intel Corporation

Comment: From what I've seen it looks like this UNCLAIMED network device is the WiFi card. I plugged in the network cable to get me online and have done a new install on 16.04 LTS AMD64. I selected the Update & Add-Ons during the install but still no wifi.

How can I claim it? I have no idea what drivers I would need if that's what I need to do.

Comment: Not making much progress on this. I've tried various distros and all the Debian 64 apart from lubuntu does the same.

I found this and I think it's the same issue but I don't understand it enough to apply it to my situation.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/help-with-wifi-driver-intel%AE-dual-band-wireless-ac-3160-a-4175515014-print/

I think I've found the correct drivers (( iwlwifi-7265-ucode-25.30.14.0.tgz ))